# Relative Mapping Cylinders

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $A$ be a nonempty topological space, and suppose $X,Z$ are topological spaces that contain $A$ as a subspace. Thus we have two pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Z,A)$. Then let $f:Z\to X$ be a continuous map that restricts to the identity on $A$ ($f|_A=\text{id}_A$). Let $M=M_f=(Z\times I \coprod X )/(z,1)\sim f(z)$ be the mapping cylinder of $f$, and let $W$ denote the quotient space obtained from $M$ by collapsing each segment $a \times I$ to a point for $a \in A$.

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, Hatcher calls the space $W$ as the **relative mapping cylinder** of $f$ and uses it in the proof of Propositions 4.15 and 4.18, using the following properties without proof:

1. $W$ contains $X$ and $Z$ as subspaces.
2. $W$ deformation retracts onto $X$.
3. $W$ is a CW complex containing both $X$ and $Z$ as subcomplexes if $(X,A)$ and $(Z,A)$ are CW pairs and $f$ is a cellular map.

How can I see that these are indeed true?

I know that $M$ contains $X$ and $Z$ as subspaces and that $M$ deformation retracts onto $X$. If 1 is true, I can then see that the deformation retraction of $M$ onto $X$ induces a deformation retract of $W$ onto $X$ so 2 will follow.

Comment: Here's a hint for (1) with $X$; $Z$ is similar. Let $p:Z\times I\sqcup X\rightarrow W$ be the quotient map. Can you show $p_{|X}$ is injective? For an open subset $U\subset X$, note that $S=(f^{-1}(U)\times I)\sqcup U$ is open, and also saturated. Thus $p(S)$ is open, and so $p(S)\cap p(X)$ is open in $p(X)$. But since $S$ is saturated, $$ p(S)\cap p(X)=p(S\cap X)=p(U)$$ This shows $p_{|X}$ is an open map, and hence a homeomorphism onto $p(X)$.